# Windows memory management

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

I'm a bit confused about Windows memory management.

I've read somewhere that every process in Windows (32 bit) gets its own 4 GB of memory - thanks to swapping to disk. But 32bit Windows can use max 4 GB. So I thought that every process only "thinks" it has 4 GB but in real it has fewer.
Am I correct?

So how can I access data from one process to another? If 2 PEs are loaded at 0x400000, how do I do that? Could you give me an example in C or ASM?

Can somebody explain this to me further? Maybe point me to some good article.

Just a brief description is enough :).
Thanks.

Comment: Do not confuse address space and physical memory amount.

Answer (score 1):

Prcesses can address up to 4 GB of addresses, which are or are not backed by "real" memory. Windows OS, even 32-bit, can address more than 4 GB but might have reasons to limit this amount, or the limits are stipulated by hardware.

- [About Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366525.aspx):

> Each process on 32-bit Microsoft Windows has its own virtual address space that enables addressing up to 4 gigabytes of memory. [...]

- [Windows Internals Book](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901) - Chapter 9: Memory Management

Comment: And how can I tell if an address is virtual or physical? Can you give me an example in asm? E.g. JMP XXX or CALL XXX - how can I tell what memory XXX is?
Or maybe I'm just missing something. What if I want to access function from DLL which is loaded at ImageBase 0x400000 from my program which is loaded too at 0x400000?

Comment: User mode apps don't deal with physical memory directly. In asm or not, you just use those addresses you are aware of. That is, you obtained a pointer from `VirtualAlloc` - you can use it. OS and kernel mode components do the mapping of virtual addresses into real memory for you. You cannot just hit unknown [memory] addresses and expect it somehow work.

Comment: OK, I get it. But how can I access another process's memory? Or DLL's? Is DLL loaded again into every process that is using it? If my app uses e.g. Kernel32.dll (which is used almost always on Windows) do I access my app's virtual adress space or another one's? Is there any shared adress space? It seems pointless to load the same DLL xxx times for every process.

Comment: Unless you want to write a driver, and I am sure you don't, you can use `ReadProcessMemory` API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx